# PHP array_merge_recursive with one array

Tags: php, arrays

I am struggling with a data structure in PHP.  I'm trying to use `array_merge_recursive` to condense an array by like keys and then grab all values instead of having them overwritten.  This is why I chose `array_merge_recursive` instead of `array_merge`.

My array is something similar to:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [App] => APP1
    [Type] => DB
  )
  [1] => Array
  (
    [App] => APP1
    [Type] => WEBSITE
  )
  [2] => Array
  (
    [App] => APP2
    [Type] => IOS
  )
)
```

I was expecting `array_merge_recursive` to combine like keys and then group the other elements into arrays however this is not the behavior I am seeing.

I am hoping to get an array like the following:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [App] => APP1
    [Type] => Array
    (
      [0] => DB
      [1] => WEBSITE
    )
  )
  [1] => Array
  (
    [App] => APP2
    [Type] => IOS
  )
)
```

Comment: `not the behavior I am seeing`  in your result you move `DB` from key  `Type` to an subarray with key `0`. Same for `WEBSITE`. How  do you thing `array_merge_recursive` works? And try to explain the logic behind your expected result. Else noone can help.

Comment: I was under the impression that `array_merge_recursive` could work with one array.  I've assumed incorrectly.  I'm just trying to combine "APP" keys together and preserve the value assigned to the "TYPE" key.

Answer (score 2):

[`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) does not do what you think it does.  You are looking for a function that restructures an array based on specific rules that are helpful to you and as such there isn't a builtin php function for that. I.e. How would PHP know that you wanted to new array to be structured by `APP` rather `TYPE`.  Assuming your array is always that simple, the easiest version of the function you want looks something like this:

```
function sortByApp($array){
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $row){
        if(!isset( $result[ $row['APP'] ] ) {
            $result[ $row['APP'] ] = array(
                'APP' => $row['APP'],
                'TYPE' => array( $row['TYPE'] ) 
            );
        }else{
            $result[ $row['APP'] ]['TYPE'] = array_merge( $result[ $row['APP'] ]['TYPE'], array($row['TYPE']) );
        }
    }
    $result =  array_values($result); //All this does is remove the keys from the top array, it isn't really necessary but will make the output more closely match what you posted.

    return $result

}
```

Note, in this solution, the value of the `TYPE` key in every `APP` will always be an array.  This makes handling the data later easier in my opinion since you don't have to worry about checking for a string vs an array.